# Advanced Calc Sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $I_n = [0,1/n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}I_n = \{0\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $x>0$, then there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x>1/n$.

Comment: Thanks. It took me a second to see that, but I got it from there.

Comment: Elegant and smart hint.